# Почему переменная обнуляется сама по себе?

Tags: массивы, ассемблер, циклы, masm32, masm

Всем добрый вечер. У меня такой вопрос, почему при выполнении программы ниже, а точнее цикла в самом конце переменная перезаписывается каким-то левым числом?

Поподробнее : Есть цикл, который повторяется `n-1` (чтобы заполнить полностью массив, не выходя за границы) и внутри него происходит чтение числа с клавиатуры в `arr[n]`. Так проблема в том, что когда всё идёт по плану и заходит на 13 раз, то переменная (счётчик для цикла) тупо перезаписывается каким-то числом и начинается INFINITE цикл :(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста в чём может быть проблема? (Сразу подскажу куда по моему нужно смотреть... на `mov [esi+ebx], eax` строчку, именно там происходит перезапись моей переменной)

```
.486                     
.model flat, stdcall                 
option casemap :none        

include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc
include    \masm32\include\msvcrt.inc
includelib  \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib
include    \masm32\macros\macros.asm

.data
 arr byte 14 dup (?)
 i dd ?

.code

start:
 mov i, 0
 lea esi, arr
 cycle1:
  inc i
  mov ebx, i
  mov eax, sval(input())
  mov [esi+ebx], eax
  mov ebx, i
  cmp ebx, 13
 jnz cycle1
 exit
end start
```

Answer (score 4):

Ну тут все просто :-)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я выделил на вашем скрине DWORD, который соответствует адресу ESI + EBX. И тут видно, что он перекрывается со счетчиком по 0x40300E. Вы пишете в 0x40300B дворд и перетираете младший байт "проблемной" переменной.